# Grails render page inside other

Tags: grails, render

I have a gsp page with a form that I would like to put inside a `div` in another gsp page. Each gsp page have diferent css configuration for 'body'. Is it possible to that that using in Grails (like render).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. In fact it's pretty simple. Best, extract the "common" part into a separate template (.gsp) file and include it into both pages.

See [render](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/render.html) for more information.

Comment: The name of the GSP should begin with a '_' so that Grails recognises it as a template, rather than a regular GSP